How to go to next page (Pagination) of Microsoft Defender API (MSAL)?
My URL is below
https://tiation.eu2.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/discovery/discovered_apps
This returns JSON response of defender API:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5ee1ee8ad68d0eb7d71cc7ac",
            "_tid": 85526804,
            "appId": 11394,
         ]
            }
    ],
    "hasNext": true,
    "total": 11902
}

It is hasnext which is fine and total. But i do not get next url or next link.
I tried multiple things like ?page= , ?offset=100&limit=1
Not able to get its documentation for paging in this API.
Can someone suggest better idea?
I got a python script which says:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
import sys
import requests

import msal

msal_tenant_id = '' ### Paste your tenant ID here
msal_client_id = '' ### Paste your Application ID here
msal_client_secret = '' ### Paste your Application key here
global_token_cache = msal.TokenCache()
msal_authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{msal_tenant_id}"
msal_scope = ["05a65629-4c1b-48c1-a78b-804c4abdd4af/.default"]

global_app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    msal_client_id, authority=msal_authority,
    client_credential=msal_client_secret,
    token_cache=global_token_cache,  # Let this app (re)use an existing token cache.
        # If absent, ClientApplication will create its own empty token cache
    )

result = global_app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=msal_scope)

if "access_token" in result:
  print("Token was obtained from:", result["token_source"])
  headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {result["access_token"]}',
  }
  filters = {
    # optionally, edit to match your filters
  }
  request_data = {
    'filters': filters,
    'limit' : 1,
    'streamId' : '<stream-id>'
  }
  APPLICATIONS_URL = f'https://<tenant-name>.<tenant-region>.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/discovery/discovered_apps/'
  records = []
  has_next = False
  while has_next:
      content = json.loads(requests.post(APPLICATIONS_URL, json=request_data, headers=headers).content)
      response_data = content.get('data', [])
      records += response_data
      print('Got {} more records'.format(len(response_data)))
      has_next = content.get('hasNext', False)
      request_data['filters'] = content.get('nextQueryFilters')

  print('Got {} records in total'.format(len(records)))
  print(records)

else:
  print("Token acquisition failed")

sys.exit(0)

But here also nextQueryFilters not got in response anywhere. So anyone can help? (BTW, I am using Postman and will code in Java and above was from Postman Response).
Update:
Pagination not working at all.
Tried following changing Skip:
{
    "limit": 100,
    "streamId": "5ee1ecbb862d7370de23c481",
    "sortDirection":"asc",
    "skip": 100
}

Still Failing

It worked as query parameter:
https://tie.com/api/v1/discovery/discovered_apps?limit=1000&streamId=5ee1ecbb862d7370de23c80&sortDirection=asc&skip=0
And bad part i got all examples as Request Body whether python or powershell.
So it was just hit and trial
